# Who is the החזו"א

Tags: names, acronyms, mishnah-berurah

I saw the roshei teivos החזו"א in the Dirshu notes to Mishna Berura in Hilchos Rosh Hodesh.  Can you tell me who it is?  Is there a general resource to figure this out?

Comment: [General Resource](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=9)

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks! That looks useful. Doesn't look like it'd've helped with this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect that that refers to the [Chazon Ish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Yeshaya_Karelitz). The letters fit, and the Chazon Ish's rulings are often quoted alongside those of the Mishna Berura.

Comment: Thank you, you must be right.  I was looking for a "Chaim Zalman..." or something.  It was actually in the Dirshu notes, not the mishna berura itself for what it's worth.

Comment: The Mishna Brurah would not quote the Chazon Ish,but dirshu would,and it is indeed the Chazon ish

Comment: @SeymoreCohen In general, most sefarim have an index towards the front of the sources they have culled from.  You can usually match up the roshei teivos to that list.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party here, but for anyone who views this answer in the future: There are a couple of resources you can use for roshei teivos: If you want to look online, you can use [this page](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=9); if you want to actually hold a sefer in your hand,  you can use this [kovetz roshei teivos](https://www.nehora.com/products/Kovetz-Rushei-Teuvos-V%27kitzirim-----%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D.html) (I have it and can personally attest to its tremendous usefulness).